# f:convertNumber does not work with my string

Tags: jsf

I have a float number that I want to display. 
I want to format the decimal digits. So i tried this:

```
<h:outputText value=" #{wui.remainingTime > 0? wui.remainingTime : '-' } h" rendered="#{wui.status eq 3}" >

     <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>

</h:outputText>
```

I also tried the pattern="#0.00"

But neither worked. The display still looks like this: 166.66667 h

Answer (score 2):

`" #{wui.remainingTime > 0? wui.remainingTime : '-' } h"` results in a string which cannot be formatted as a number. You best split this into multiple output texts and instruct which of them to render:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{wui.status eq 3}">
    <h:outputText value="#{wui.remainingTime}"
                  rendered="#{wui.remainingTime gt 0}">
        <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
    </h:outputText>
    <h:outputText value="-" rendered="#{wui.remainingTime le 0}"/>
    <h:outputText value=" h"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Or look at http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Numbers and extend one of them and create your own converter that has a 'postfix' attribute